What is the name of this animated short about a war against an unknown/unseen enemy?
Recall seeing an animated short about a war against an unknown/unseen enemy. Believe the short was on a Studio Ghibli DVD as "extra" content, but not 100%  sure about that. I recall canons being the weapon of choice, but beyond that only recall that you never see the enemy, and believe in fact that even the civilization does not know who the enemy is; can't even recall the city being attacked, just the city spending all day making ammo, firing canons, etc.
Any ideas what this short is?

Found it. The name of the short is Cannon Fodder by director and screenwriter by Katsuhiro Otomo, who is best known as the creator of the manga Akira and its animated film adaptation.

In a walled city perpetually at war, everyone's livelihood depends
  upon maintaining and firing the enormous cannons that make up most of
  the city. Nearly every building in the city is equipped with a cannon
  of varying size, able to fire huge artillery shells over the city
  walls. The story is centered on a young boy and his father, who works
  as a lowly cannon-loader.
The city is surrounded by clouds of smoke and dust provoked by the
  shots fired by the cannons. Despite news of successful bombardment of
  the "enemy city" by the local media, there is not any visual
  confirmation that it is true, or even if there is an enemy at all.
In the end the boy comes home from school and hears a television news
  reporter talking about the near-destruction of the enemy city. The boy
  hops into his bed, saying that someday he wants to be the exalted
  officer who fires the cannons, and not be a simple worker like his
  father. As he sleeps, a blue light sweeps across the window. Is it
  from the enemy or the city?
Through unusual animation techniques the illusion is created that the
  film consists of one continuous shot or long take.
Written and directed by Katsuhiro Otomo. Music by Hiroyuki Nagashima.


